# What are the trade-offs when denormalizing for a computed column?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization, calculated-columns

I hope I am not asking a too obvious question here.

For my current project I am designing a relatively simple database using sql server 2008. For one of the tables I have decided to introduce a 'Computed Column' (not persisted). Its expression is simply the product of 2 other numeric columns and its sole reason for existence is convenience (I am doing some one-way databinding to a webpage).

I realized however that using a computed column violates the first normal form. This got me wondering: Wat are the trade-offs? If my only reason for the computed column is convenience, does it outweigh the denormalization?

Comment: Obviously there is a slight additional CPU overhead on the database Server of calculating something that could be calculated in another tier and a slight addition of network traffic by returning the additional column. If it's not persisted there is no additional overhead for CUD operations and it takes no disc space so will cause no additional I/O.

Comment: A SQL table is in 1NF if it has at least one key, has unique column names and all the columns are non-nullable. Persisted or not, a computed column doesn't violate 1NF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"using a computed column violates the first normal form": not at all ! It's not stored, it is re-calculated with the latest data at all time. So it is an excellent solution, just like having a calculated column in a view.

Comment: So what you are saying is that as long as the computed column is not persisted, it doed not influence normalization?

Comment: @rewinder: That's what I believe, yes !

Answer (score 0):

> Its expression is simply the product
>   of 2 other numeric columns and its
>   sole reason for existence is
>   convenience (I am doing some one-way
>   databinding to a webpage).

Then put the calculation in your SELECT statement, not into the database.