# MySQL, should a field be created to store the relational table calculation?

Tags: mysql

I know that:

> No, you would never store a value that could be calculated from other columns in the database. Storing calculated values is a violation of database normalization.

But what about the calculated value from the relational table? For example, amount in orders is calculated from the order_products table with the formula sum (price * qty). Should I save this value in the orders table?

Comment: Generally, you wouldn't store derived data, but it's your model so ultimately it's up to you. If the price changes then it might make sense to record the sale price directly, rather than recalculating it from historical data.

Comment: you could calculate it anytime using the formula without a save. But, if you use it regularly, it is okay to save. Still not recommended!

Comment: *you would never store a value that could be calculated from other columns in the database* This is not true in general. An example - the value is calculated initially, then source values may be altered but the calculated value must stay unchanged.

Comment: *Should I save this value in the orders table?* You must decide this by yourself only. This may improve performance but it may give incorrect data in emergency situations. Do not forget to create service stored procedure which recalculates this column values when data inconsistence is detected or suspicion is raised.

Comment: I think that should be ok for huge data calculation to improve performance, however that will not be good for something likes order_porducts, 
for example I think this can be useful to show comments count for multiple posts without making multiple counts form billions of records

Comment: @Alsemany well I think this is reasonable for big data, as long as the data has to be tight.
I will not add the amount field to the order table. I will consider using views for faster queries.
I have the transactions table when the customer makes a transaction that will get the amount to be paid from the attached order_products table maybe I have to save this amount in case the record in order_products gets deleted leading to the guest the actual payment is no longer correct. Right, everyone?

Comment: @AnNguyễn you can use soft deleting like Laravel or with your own philosophy, that's mean the data actually will not be deleted from the database, but marked as deleted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the trade-offs when denormalizing for a computed column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315467/what-are-the-trade-offs-when-denormalizing-for-a-computed-column)

Comment: This is not clear. What do you mean, "from the relational table"? Do you mean a value calculated from *the same* table?